# how to avoid screen termination once the job is done

Tags: linux, scripting, shell-scripting, gnu-screen

using a shell script i am ceating multiple screen in which i m running rsync cmnd with below syntax, n i m able to do so.

```
screen -dmS "$SESSION_NAME" "$COMMAND" "$ARGUMENTS"
```

but as soon as rsync completed , the screen which was generated with above syntax , automatically got terminated.

is there any way to avoid screen terminations ??

Comment: Probably should start a shell, which runs rsync instead of running rsync directly.

Comment: @Gnudiff ..  can u please elaborate it more.